# HTML5 Canvas faster on Firefox than on Chrome! Why?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

I have found this code to draw on a canvas. In firefox it works fine but in the latest Chrome the performance lacks. If the mouse is moved very fast the drawn line in behinde the cursor in Chrome. Why?

[**js fiddle canvas**](http://jsfiddle.net/FgNQk/35/)

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var width  = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.height = height;
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
        this.down = true;   
        this.X = e.pageX ;
        this.Y = e.pageY ;
        this.color = rgb();
    }, 0);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
        this.down = false;          
    }, 0);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {

        if(this.down) {
             with(ctx) {
                beginPath();
                moveTo(this.X, this.Y);
                lineTo(e.pageX , e.pageY );
                strokeStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
                ctx.lineWidth=3;
                stroke();
             }
             this.X = e.pageX ;
             this.Y = e.pageY ;
        }
    }, 0);
```

Comment: I don't seem to have the same problems as you do. Maybe the strength of your PC has to do with it?

Comment: but if my pc shall be slow, why is it working in firefox?

Comment: Works fine for me on the latest Chrome.

Comment: a plugin or like might slow down things. The fps meter, for instance, has a quite bad impact on performances (seems to create quite some garbage and require too much time for the drawing).

Comment: I deactivated all plug-ins, but still it does not work

Comment: Why?  There's an app for that !!  Get to know the built in Chrome performance profiler:  http://globaldev.co.uk/2012/08/finding-javascript-bottlenecks/

Answer (score 0):

The speed of executing javascript is different in each browser, so it can run better in firefox for you. It also depends on your own PC performance.

The `with` statement also slows down the execution.

This is because with() appends an extra set of variables to the beginning of the scope chain described above. This extra item means that anytime any variable is called, the Javascript engine must loop through the with() variables, then the local variables, then the global variables.

So with() essentially gives local variables all the performance drawbacks of global ones, and in turn derails Javascript optimization.

This why not to use `with` explanation comes from [here](http://jonraasch.com/blog/10-javascript-performance-boosting-tips-from-nicholas-zakas)

Comment: thanks for the advice but it does not change the performance. I want to develop for chrome so what can I do? this one is working fine in both: [sumo paint](http://www.sumopaint.com/app/)

Comment: @Dennis Sorry, I meant after I corrected that sample code, the performance was still bad

Comment: That sumo paint is coded in flash, which is usually faster at this kind of stuff.

Comment: In conclusion HTML5 is behind flash? and Chrome is worse than FireFox?

Comment: I wouldnt make such conclusions. I would just say that they both have pros and cons.

Comment: In the [full jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/FgNQk/), `rgb()` is a function that returns a random `rgb(r,g,b)` string. It's not a bug, and either way, your `"rgb()"` is introducing the bug of having an invalid color value (defaults to black when I tested). For fun, I would replace `"rgb(0,0,0)"` with the `rgb()` function call too.